# Sed, delete strings not starting with punctuation

Tags: regex, string, parsing, replace, sed

I need to delete all the following substring from a text:

```
</p>

<p class="calibre2">
```

But not the ones preceded by punctuation, like "." or "?" or "!"

so delete the following

```
Hello</p>

<p class="calibre2"> World
```

--> output desired "Hello World"

But leave the same the following, without modifications:

```
Hello.</p>

<p class="calibre2"> World
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) work?

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)? How about [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)?

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{(?<![[:punct:]])</p>\s*<p class="calibre2">}{}g' file
```

Comment: It's almost ok, but I don't need all the punctuation, but only ? ! and . I want it to match for commas semicolon etc

Comment: It's almost ok, but I don't need all the punctuation, but only ? ! and . I want it to match for commas semicolon etc, and how can I make perl update the files, ex to update a bunch of *.html?

Comment: Do you know how to alter `[[:punct:]]` to only match the characters you're interested in? Perl has a `-i` option (like sed) to edit files in-place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with help of regex.

I can use this pattern to replace

```
\<\/p\>\s{0,}\<p[\w\W]{0,}?\>
```

in PHP  you can do that with this code

```
$a = 'Hello</p>

<p class="calibre2"> World';

$pattern = '/\<\/p\>\s{0,}\<p[\w\W]{0,}?\>/';

echo preg_replace($pattern,'',$a);
```

Comment: You change {0,} to * , of course these are the same. 
But [\w\W]  and . is not the same. (dot) not matches line breaks such as \r , \n. 
In that situation , this is possible , tag can be write in two lines. 
</p>

<p 
class="calibre2"
>
So i cannot use .* for this situation